# drcsim: keyboard_teleop hangs at line 75 self.client.wait_for_server()

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The keyboard_teleop walking demo works on some machines, and on others it hangs at line 75

```
self.client.wait_for_server()
```

I tried sudo apt-get remove and reinstall drcsim-nightly but that didn't solve the issue.

Anyone else seen this?
Is there some dependency that must be installed separately?

I was told this can indicate that the actionlib server didn't start properly; the log file shows:

```
rospy.client][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,018: init_node, name[/walking_client], pid[7581]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,018: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,018: Started XML-RPC server [http://computer:57220/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,018: ROS Slave URI: [http://computer:57220/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,018: _ready: http://computer:57220/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,019: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,019: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,119: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,119: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,122: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,124: initializing /clock core topic
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,126: connected to core topic /clock
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,137: topic[/clock] adding connection to [http://computer:56967/], count 0
[rosout][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,143: Waiting for atlas/bdi_control
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,254: topic[/atlas/mode] adding connection to [/gazebo], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,353: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2013-05-01 18:01:31,354: topic[/atlas/control_mode] adding connection to [/gazebo], count 0
```

That's the output of the walking_client.log; the only message on screen is the "Waiting for atlas/bdi_control" message

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2638/drcsim:-keyboard_teleop-hangs-at-line-75-self.client.wait_for_server()/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

did you start keyboard teleop by roslaunch?  i.e.

```
roslaunch atlas_utils keyboard_teleop.launch
```

alternatively, be sure to start `actionlib_server` first,

```
rosrun atlas_msgs actionlib_server
```

then do

```
roslaunch atlas_utils keyboard_teleop.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-05-01**:
:-(   This is where I'm tempted to toss this post down the memory hole.  When in doubt carefully read instructions, and don't go from memory and use "rosrun" instead "roslaunch".  Thanks. Must have had 5steps.py in my head.